# What are these weird white spots and black spots on my Monstera?

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, diseases, insects, monstera

I used a microscope on one of those black dots and took a picture.
I also found this insect that looks suspicious.
I don't know if the white spots are related to the black dots.
What can I do?

[image]

| [image] | [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |